# "Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is not allowed" occurs when trying to delete "many" set in optional relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a one-to-many relationship where I am trying to delete a set of instances on the "many" side, but keep getting the exception "Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is not allowed". This is Entity Framework 6.1.1.

The relationship is one-to-many from Teacher to Course. The two classes are defined as:

```
[Table("Course")]
public partial class Course {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? TeacherId { get; set; }

    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}


[Table("Teacher")]
public partial class Teacher
{
    public Teacher()
    {
        Course = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Course { get; set; }
}
```

The code that tries to delete the courses, is part of an import: A set of courses is coming in, and the courses that are in the database but not part of the incoming courses, should be deleted from the database. (In addition, the courses that are part of the incoming set but not in the database, should be created, but this seems to work).

```
var existingCourses = ctx.Courses.ToList();
var toCreate = incomingCourses.Where(x => !existingCourses.Contains(x)).ToList();
var coursesToDelete = existingCourses.Where(x => !incomingCourses.Contains(x)).ToList();
ctx.Courses.RemoveRange(coursesToDelete);
ctx.SaveChanges(); // The exception occurs here
```

The incoming set of courses are parsed from an XML file to a DTO. Before comparing them to the existing courses, they are placed in a list as:

```
var incomingCourses = incomingDtos.Select(x => new Course
{
    Teacher = new Teacher { TeacherName = x.TeacherNameFromXml }
}.ToList();
```

There are other properties on the Course entity that identifies the course, but I have not shown them here as I suppose they are irrelevant.

When debugging, I noticed that the Teacher property of the Courses that are being deleted are non-empty before the call to `RemoveRange()` but null afterwards.. So it seems that there is some kind of cascade delete taking place.

I have tried to remove all cascade deletes via my DbContext and also specifying the relationship there. This changes nothing.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    public MyDbContext() {}

    public MyDbContext(string connectionString) {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Teacher> Teacher { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>()
            .HasMany(x => x.Course)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Teacher)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.TeacherId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the `incomingCourses` collection?

Comment: @LukasKabrt I made an edit with some information about `incomingCourses`

Comment: My guess ... EF doesn't know anything about objects in your `incomingCourses` collection and it can't wrap it's head around it. I would try to compare entities by IDs in your `Where` statements

Comment: Good guess! I have posted an answer where I compare DTOs instead of the actual `Course` objects. I am not sure why `existingCourses.Where(x => !incomingCourses.Contains(x)).ToList();` would return anything else than actual objects from the `existingCourses` set, though. Perhaps someone can elaborate on the answer?

Comment: Just faced the same issue. The root cause was that the entities you are trying to delete are loaded into the `teacher.Course` property. Attempting to delete the courses right from the context leads EF to think that you are trying to also add the entities as these are still in the `teacher.Course` collection. The solution would be to clear  `teacher.Course` before you remove the entities from the context and save your changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from @LukasKabrt pointed me in the right direction. Instead of comparing the Course objects directly, I convert the existing courses to DTOs "temporarily" inside the LINQ and compare DTOs. Now I am able to delete all from `coursesToDelete`

```
var coursesToDelete = (
      from e in existing
      let dto = new CourseDto(e)
      where !incomingDtos.Contains(dto)
      select e).ToList();
```